# Show divs based on number entered into text box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to show divs based on the number entered into an input field. If the user enters 1 none of the guest fields should display. If the user enters 2 `.guest-0` should display. If the user enters 3. `guest-0` and `guest-1` should display and so on. If the user changes their answer, it should reflect their changes.

```
<p>Attendees</p>
<input type="text" class="attendees" max="4">

<div class="guest-0">
    <span>guest 1 name</span>
    <span>guest 1 more</span>
</div>
<div class="guest-1">
    <span>guest 2 name</span>
    <span>guest 2 more</span>
</div>
<div class="guest-2">
    <span>guest 3 name</span>
    <span>guest 3 more</span>
</div>
<div class="guest-3">
    <span>guest 4 name</span>
    <span>guest 4 more</span>
</div>

<script>
    $('div[class*="guest-"]').hide();
</script>
```

This can be done in either jQuery or pure JS

Comment: What have you already tried and didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.attendees').on('change', function(){
    $value = Math.max(0, Number(this.value) - 1);
    $('div[class*="guest-"]').hide().slice(0, $value).show();
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lw83nohg/)

Answer (score 0):

You could track the user input's using the `input` event, then get the value of the input and substract 1 to get the number of elements you want to show, then use the `.slice()` to select the range you want to show :

```
$('[class^="guest-"]').hide().slice(0, Math.max(0, this.value - 1)).fadeIn("slow");
```

Target all the element start with `guest-` using the start sign `^=` in your selector :

```
$('[class^="guest-"]')
```

Code:

```js
$('[class^="guest-"]').hide();

$('input.attendees').on('input', function() {
  $('[class^="guest-"]').hide().slice(0, Math.max(0, this.value - 1)).fadeIn("slow");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Attendees</p>
<input type="text" class="attendees" max="4">

<div class="guest-0">
  <span>guest 1 name</span>
  <span>guest 1 more</span>
</div>
<div class="guest-1">
  <span>guest 2 name</span>
  <span>guest 2 more</span>
</div>
<div class="guest-2">
  <span>guest 3 name</span>
  <span>guest 3 more</span>
</div>
<div class="guest-3">
  <span>guest 4 name</span>
  <span>guest 4 more</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jQuery solution:

```js
$('.guest').hide();

$('.attendees').change(function() {
  $('.guest').hide();
  var inputNum = $(this).val();
  $('.guest').each(function() {
    var displayNum = $(this).attr("display");
    if (inputNum > displayNum) {
      $(this).show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Attendees</p>
<input type="text" class="attendees" max="4">

<div class="guest" display="1">
  <span>guest 1 name</span>
  <span>guest 1 more</span>
</div>
<div class="guest" display="2">
  <span>guest 2 name</span>
  <span>guest 2 more</span>
</div>
<div class="guest" display="3">
  <span>guest 3 name</span>
  <span>guest 3 more</span>
</div>
<div class="guest" display="4">
  <span>guest 4 name</span>
  <span>guest 4 more</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

pleas try this :

```
$('div[class*="guest-"]').hide();

$(".attendees").change(function() {
  inp = (parseInt($(this).text()) - 1);
  for( i = 0 ; i < inp ; i++)
    $(".guest-" + i).show();

});
```

Comment: This code does not include  `.show()` or any other method to make the appropriate divs appear.